# what's the different between live and delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery

like the title said , this two function is in jquery :)

Comment: Which part the documentation don't you understand?

Answer (score 4):

[Googled](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=jquery%20delegate%20vs%20live&aq=1&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=jquery%20delegate) -
As per the documentation on the jquery site.

> Since the .live() method handles
>   events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not
>   possible to stop propagation of live
>   events. Similarly, events handled by
>   .delegate() will always propagate to
>   the element to which they are
>   delegated; event handlers on any
>   elements below it will already have
>   been executed by the time the
>   delegated event handler is called.

```
$("table").delegate("td", "hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Is equivalent to the following code written using .live():

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $("td", this).live("hover", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Its all in the docs.

```
$("table").delegate("td", "hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Is equivalent to the following code written using `.live()`:

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $("td", this).live("hover", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The ".live()" API has the disadvantage of needlessly building up a jQuery object from the target selector before establishing the bubbled event handler on the `<body>` element. Otherwise you can express ".live()" in terms of ".delegate()":

```
$(something).live('click', func);
```

is effectively the same as

```
$('body').delegate(something, 'click', func);
```

except that the latter is more efficient because the "something" selector will not actually be applied to the page while setting up the handler.

Answer (score 0):

just read the api documentation.

delegate expects a selector as root element, whereas live does not